# Вывести один из нескольких тегов, сравнивая их по дате во вложенном элементе

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl

Есть xml вида:

```
<tag>
    ...
    <date>2022-11-16</date>
    ...
</tag>
<tag>
    ...
    <date>2022-11-17</date>
    ...
</tag>
```

Прошу подсказать какими средствами XSLT воспользоваться, чтобы выбирался только тот тег, в котором дата в элементе  была бы самой свежей? Тегов tag может быть от одного, до бесконечности. Спасибо!

Comment: Какой у вас процессор XSLT и его соответствие стандартам XSLT: 1.0, 2.0 или 3.0.?

Comment: Версия 1.0, насчет процессора не уверен, но если правильно посмотрел в Stylus Studio - Built-in.

Comment: Stylus Studio имеет встроенный XSLT процессор Saxon . Он совместим с XSLT 1.0, 2.0 и 3.0. Вы можете увидеть это в сценарии XSLT, вкладка Процессор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полезные XSLT фрагменты.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<!--Получите последнюю дату и поместите ее в переменную-->
<xsl:variable name="latest_date">
    <xsl:for-each select="tag">
        <xsl:sort select="date" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
    
<!--Чтобы увидеть переменную-->
<xsl:value-of select="$latest_date"/>
    
<!--Чтобы использовать переменную-->
/root/tag/date[text()=$latest_date]
```